# Preventing fc-next-button from refetching events

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, fullcalendar

I am working now quite a time with fullcalendar and built a big application around it.

When looking for some performance improvements I found some behavior, I would like to "switch off" or work around if possible.

So here is what I have and what happens. When pushing the .fc-next-button button, I trigger a script via AJAX call, that helps me to read the correct data from my database and that tells the calendar how many days and which view has to be displayed. After this ajax call, I refetch the events via `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')` and I send the calendar to the correct date `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', wishdate)`.

This works fine.

But, while looking for more performance I saw in the Chrome Developer console, that as soon as I hit the .fc-next-button the calendar refetches the events.

It looks like this:

ajax_events.asp --> the file to build the json for the eventSources [] part

ajax_manipulate_event.asp?act=manipulate&pager_forward=1&pager_up_down=plus
--> the script to calculate the dates and views to be displayed

ajax_events.asp --> again the file to build the json.

So the first call of ajax_events.asp happens right after I hit the button, and is not needed. The other calls are fine and happen to the right time. Can I stop this first call from being executed?

The code I use looks like that:

```html
$(".fc-next-button").click(function()
{
    $('#loading').show();
    var StrEvent = "act=manipulate&pager_forward=1&pager_up_down=plus";
    $.ajax ({     
        type: "POST",
        url: "<%= fullcalendar_path %>ajax_manipulate_event.asp?"+StrEvent,
        data: "order=" + StrEvent,
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            var str = data;
            dummy = str.split("XXX")[0];
            wishdate = str.split("XXX")[1];
            asset_id = str.split("XXX")[2];
            wish_date_up_down = str.split("XXX")[3];
            change_view_to = str.split("XXX")[4];
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', wishdate);
            if (change_view_to == "month")
            {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'month');
                $("#selectservice").hide(1000);
                $("#<%= session("reservierung_wishdate_from") %>").hide(500);
                $("#wishdateupdown").hide(250);
                $("#external-events").fadeOut(250);
            };
            if (change_view_to == "day")
            {
                if (asset_id == "0")
                {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#selectservice").show(1000);
                    $("#<%= session("reservierung_wishdate_from") %>").show(500);
                    $("#wishdateupdown").show(250);
                    $("#external-events").fadeIn(250);
                    if (wish_date_up_down == "1")
                    {
                        <% if session("agenda_is_app_backend") = 1 or session("agenda_is_app_frontend") = 1 then %>
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaSingleDay');
                        <% end if %>
                        <% if session("agenda_is_backend") = 1 then %>
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaTwoDay');
                        <% end if %>
                    };
                    if (wish_date_up_down == "2")
                    {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaThreeDay');
                    };
                    if (wish_date_up_down == "3")
                    {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaFourDay');
                    };
                    if (wish_date_up_down == "4")
                    {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaFiveDay');
                    };
                    if (wish_date_up_down == "5")
                    {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaSixDay');
                    };
                };
            };
            if (change_view_to == "sevendays")
            {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaSevenDay');
            };
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the easiest way would be not to show the default next/prev buttons and implement your own which don't respond to fullCalendar's normal triggers.

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks.